# What does the character '>' and '&' mean in bootstrap less modules?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am very new to bootstrap and I would like to customize it. I am confused when I see '>' and '&' character. What does that mean? Is that present in less documentation. Is that some sort of nesting? Please see sample code below.

```
.navbar-nav {
    > .open > a {
      &,
      &:hover,
      &:focus {
        background-color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-bg;
        color: @navbar-inverse-link-active-color;
      }
    }
```

This might be the easiest question, don't hate me for this. Thanks folks.

Comment: > is just normal CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS, the ">" character means that only "first nested" elements will be targeted ("direct child" elements).

that means in the following scenario:

```
   <div id="a">
       <div id="b">
          <div id="c">
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

then in CSS `#a > div` would only target `<div id="b">` and **NOT** `<div id="c">`

without the `>` character, `#a div` would target both "b" and "c".

---

As for the **&** character in LESS:

The ampersand selector is most commonly used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class to an existing selector:

```
a {
    color: blue;
    &:hover {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

The inner selector in this example compiles to a:hover. Without the &, it would compile to a :hover (a descendant selector that matches hovered elements inside of  tags).

Read more at http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/

Answer (score 0):

The `>` character refers to the direct children of certain element.

The `&` character is used in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) for [reference of the parent selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_).

Comment: Thanks Felix, can you explain a bit more regarding '>'?

Comment: @user3187337 [the CSS specification is a good place to start](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) — by *direct children*, Felix means that *in*direct children aren't selected (for example their children's children).